# Can't create initial admin user in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect

it shows an error "we are sorry an internal error occurred" while entered username password and confirm password. How can i create initial admin user?

Comment: Hi there. The quality of this question is quite low. Please read the guide "how do I ask a good question?" and improve yours: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running Keycloak in docker container then you can define admin name and password during startup:

```
docker run --name keycloak -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

Otherwise, you can add the user as follows (this actually what is done in docker container behind the scenes):

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh --user "$KEYCLOAK_USER" --password "$KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: @Madeo, just double check and it works fine. And this is just instruction from an official page [jboss/keycloak](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)

Comment: This answer is outdated, [Replacement for add-user-keycloak.sh | Github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10302) - Apparently the `add-user-keycloak.sh` bin is no longer available since Keycloak 17.

Answer (score 0):

The admin console is available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin
```